# CSS won't link to my HTML

Tags: html, css, localhost

I've been trying to resolve this issue with my website (www.wintonbrownmusic.online). I've attached a picture of how my site looks locally. When I upload it through GoDaddy, the site looks differently. I understand that others have had this issue but not sure where/how to change the CSS file to link to my website so it'll look the way that it should. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your hosting / creating it with, but I had a quick look at your site and found one issue.

Your HTML file is looking for the bootstrap.css file in the assets/css folder, but it appears to be in the root folder.

unless your hosting with something that is *supposed* to find it there. 
not sure.

but when is use http://www.wintonbrownmusic.online/assets/css/bootstrap.css is doesn't work, but if I use http://www.wintonbrownmusic.online/bootstrap.css it does work.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with path, If you open the console in inspect element it will show you that you have problems in calling the required files css, js, and other files.

[image]

You need to upload folders properly in the host, you need to add folders like you have in local folders in your computers. "assets" folder is missing and you just upload files inside there.

Answer (score 0):

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> change your folder name as either assets or css ....
>   **assets/css** is a folder name because of the slash (/) browser looking for css folder  inside assets folder...just give the folder
>   name correctly try to avoid usage of special character ,punctutation
>   in folder name